# Tension in wire rope vs fiber rope vs metal rod

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

I am trying to understand if tension in wire ropes acts identically to fiber ropes.  In both, I consider a rope made of strands.

To be concrete consider the following situation.

A rope is strung completely horizontally between two trees, 20 meters apart.  A weight of 20kg is placed in the middle of the rope. The rope sags by 0.1 meters.

With a fiber rope, we deduce that the tension in the rope is ~ 1 ton ( 20k/2 / sin(atan(0.01) ~ 1000kg)/.

Is the same true also for a wire rope?

If the answer is yes, then consider the following situation. A 20m metal rod (rather than a rope) is placed perfectly horizontally between the trees, resting on the branches.  A 20kg
weight is placed in the middle and the rod sags (bends) 0.1m. In this case, clearly, the the "tension" along the rod is not 1 ton.  Indeed, the rod is only resting on the branches, with no horizontal pull on the trees.

the difference between the rope and the rod seems to be that the rope can bend more easily than the rod.

My question is: what is going on?

- with the metal rod, why is there no tension along the rod?  what are the physical forces at play?
- is the wire rope identical to the fiber rope or in between the fiber
  and the rod?

Throughout - ignore the weight of the rope/rod.

Comment: I think a more appropriate title would be "Tension in a wire vs. tension in a rod". Because from a physicist's point of view the only difference between a wire and a rod is that wire has no thickness. I think it does not matter if it is a metal or fiber or wood. That is a question for materials scientists or civil engineers.

Comment: Rope is stranded, regardless of what it is made of. If you ask someone for metal rope, you will get something made of many strands. If you mean to say single solid metal wire, or thin metal rod, you should clarify it. As it is it is not clear whether you really mean to ask whether a [stranded] wire rope is different from a [stranded] fiber rope (they're not, material doesn't matter), or whether you mean to ask if a single strand metal wire (basically a rod) is different than a fiber rope. You jump back and forth between "metal rod" and "wire rope" so it is unclear.

Comment: @DKNguyen
 In "wire rope" I indeed mean "stranded".  You are all saying that the material does not matter,  but is this really the case?  the point is that wire rope are not as bendable as fiber ropes.  In the limit, when they are altogether unbendable, then they act as a rod. So, the question is really if the bendability of a rope influences the tension.

Comment: @user154729 It doesn't matter so far as the fact that all the phenomena present are identical just in differing amounts. The last sentence is key to your question and I think it would be more easily understood if a lot less was written and focused mainly around that point. Intuitively the rigidity would affect the angle and the if the tension is dependent on that angle, then tension would be affected. However, there is such a thing as stretch and that obfuscates role of angle.

Answer (score 1):

For 1st question

> with the metal rod, why is there no tension along the rod? what are the physical forces at play?

How can you say that there is no tension in the rod. See following diagram:

[image]

For 2nd question

> is the wire rope identical to the fiber rope or in between the fiber and the rod?

Wire rope and fibre rope both are tied to tree but rod is just placed over branch. So in ropes longitudinal stress would do the job but in in rod there would be shear stress into play. So wire is more close to rope than rod.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a metal rod and a rope (by which I mean an ideal rope) is that the rod is rigid - it will resist an attempt to deform it sideways. The rod can therefore transmit shear forces along its length - forces that are perpendicular to the rod - whereas the ideal rope can only transmit tensile forces in a direction that is parallel to the rope at any point.

A real rope has some ability to transmit shear forces, but this is usually quite limited.

Comment: All ropes have some rigidity. Just because a fiber rope's rigidity isn't noticeable to the human experience doesn't mean it's fundamentally different than a rope whose rigidity is noticeable. Indeed, just increase the diameter of that rope that "isn't rigid" and the rigidity will increase to the point where you can easily notice it. If your answer is referring to spherical cows and not real rope and rod, then it should be made clear.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, I meant an ideal rope. I have amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  So, since the wire rope is more rigid than a fiber rope, does this mean that the tension along the rope is indeed smaller than along the fiber rope?

Comment: The tension in the wire rope will be greater because it sags less. If the tension is $T$ and the angle from the vertical at the middle of the rope is $\theta$  then $2T\cos \theta = mg$. So if $\theta$ is greater (as it is for the wire rope) then $T$ must also be greater.